# How to change the "Add new comment" message for custom comment form?

Tags: theming, 8, comments

I have custom content type called *books* that represents a book that can be reviewed by using a custom comment type called *reviews*.

My problem is the comment form title above the comment form shows as "Add New comment", which I need to change as "review the book".

How can I change this to read as "review the book"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Add new comment* header is a part of theme layer.

You can copy your theme's existing comment template (e.g. **core/themes/classy/templates/field/field--comment.html.twig** if you're using a theme that utilizes the base classy theme) over to your theme's template dir and rename it to match your specified field (e.g. **field--field-my_custom_comment_machinename.html.twig**). If you're not familiar with this, enable [Twig template debugging](https://www.drupal.org/node/1906392).

Once you've create a copy of the template, you can then edit template header as you see fit.

Comment: This works when "Show reply form on the same page as comments" is checked. If i want the form in a separate page, everything from the link to title goes back to add new comment. Any suggestion on what template i should edit?

Comment: Twig debugging can help here again. It looks like the template hints are ***page--comment--reply--node--field-my_custom_comment_machinename.html.twig*** & ***html--comment--reply--node--field-my_custom_comment_machinename.html.twig***. That might be overkill for what you are doing and you might get by with something more granular (perhaps .theme preprocess functions).

Comment: lol... now i've to learn preprocess functions... Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: This will change in a good direction in Drupal 8.3: https://www.drupal.org/node/2546116

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the `template_preprocess_field__comment()` hook in your custom module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_field__comment().
 */
function MY_MODULE_preprocess_field__comment(&$variables) {
  switch ($variables['field_name']) {
    //field_message_custom is your custom comment field name
    case 'field_message_custom':
      $variables['add_new_comment'] = t('Review the book');
      break;
    default:
      $variables['add_new_comment'] = t('Add new comment');
  }
}
```

And now you change use the `add_new_comment` variable in your field--comment.html.twig this line:

```
<h2 class="title comment-form__title">{{ 'Add new comment'|t }}</h2>
```

for this line:

```
<h2 class="title comment-form__title">{{ add_new_comment }}</h2>
```

**After this clean your cache.**

It seems that we will be able to change this message in the interface in Drupal 8.3. Read: [You can add a review, opinion, greeting, etc. comment type but not change the "Add new comment" text](https://www.drupal.org/node/2546116)